# Pith and Gist as synonyms

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Pith and gist show as up synonyms on many of the dictionaries. But the gist word is used more often and pith is very rarely used in examples. Can somebody clear me the right usage of both these words.

*He watched the trailer but he still did not get the gist of the movie.*
Can we replace the gist in the above sentece with pith ?

Comment: I only vaguely know what "pith" means, and I suspect this is true for many US English speakers.  To the extent that I do understand "pith" I would not consider it to be a synonym for the idiomatic use of "gist".

Comment: @HotLicks Pith is mentioned as essence or the heart of something. Gist is a quick summary of the essentials. Do you think this is right?

Comment: Yes and no.  The terms are used in different contexts.

Comment: @HotLicks So which is a better word to use?

Comment: Depends on your context.  And what precisely you mean.

Comment: If he did not get the "pith" of the movie, he did not comprehend it's "heart" -- the underlying emotional meaning.  If he did not get the "gist" of the movie he didn't comprehend it's plot, or perhaps he missed the point that it was a parody or allegory of some sort.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks Sir, now its meaning is clear to me.

Comment: @HotLicks That would be a fine answer.

Comment: The idiom is 'get the gist of it'. You just don't use 'pith' there. YOu just don't say that someone 'kicked the pail' when they died.

Comment: If I see "pith" I probably think of a "pith helmet".  I would probably never say "the pith of a movie".  I may say "the movie was pithy."

Comment: @HotLicks...as one orange said to the other orange: "Beats the pith outa me."

Comment: @Cascabel - Now you got me pithed!!

Answer (score 1):

If he did not get the "pith" of the movie, he did not comprehend it's "heart" -- the underlying emotional meaning. If he did not get the "gist" of the movie he didn't comprehend it's plot, or perhaps he missed the point that it was a parody or allegory of some sort.